# current_cred in Rust

Tags: rust, linux-kernel, ebpf, linux-security-module

I am implementing a Linux Security Module (LSM) in Rust using eBPF (aya-rs). While I was able to define different hooks, I havent been able to get the current task's credentials (as LSM modules do by calling current_cred).

How can I get them?

I tried to define current_cred as an extern function

```
#[allow(improper_ctypes)]
extern "C" {
    fn current_cred() -> *const cred;
}
```

But I received the following error during compilation:

```
function 0x90 not found while relocating `file_open`
```

Comment: `current_cred` is a macro so you won't be able to "call" it. You will need to get ahold of `current` and do the same as `current_cred` does, i.e. `rcu_dereference_protected(current->cred, 1)`. Not sure how to do that in Rust or if that is even possible.

Comment: Or you wrap the macro in a c lib to be called with extern "C", is this possible?